# Tree view of a directory/folder in Windows?

Tags: windows, tree, directory, windows-explorer

In Linux/KDE, I can see a directory as a tree. How can I do it in Windows 7?

Consider I do NOT mean "Windows Explorer". This just shows the directories, I also want the files.

Comment: @Luke: it is useful for me, I always use it where it is available (Linux/Mac). And I do not need a tree view of the system32 directory, just of my own projects (e.g. you can get a tree view of your source code).

Comment: @Luke: What do you mean with: "it's not terribly hard to do it yourself"? Should I learn the Windows API and write such an utility by myself?

Comment: This site is about programming so I assumed you were looking for either a 3rd party control or to write it yourself.  I'm sure there are programs out there that already do it, though I'm not familiar with any.

Comment: This might be more suited for SuperUser instead of SO.

Comment: It is very useful to have a tree view in windows. I am facing situations where I have to add a module or library that has lots of files. Easily than 50 files and sometimes well over 100 files. On my MacBook Pro, I see the enclosing folder collapsed and I just drap it with the mouse and stage it for the next commit. On Windows, I have to scroll down and select individual files. Such a waste of time. And it often happened that I missed some files during the commit. Even on system32, tree is supported. I develop on MS Visual Studio and there is a tree view control. I have used it several times.

Comment: The Dolphin file manager has a win64 binary available here https://binary-factory.kde.org/job/Dolphin_Release_win64/
Works like a charm

Comment: system internals `du` can do tree with some metadata too.

Answer (score 192):

In the Windows command prompt you can use "tree /F" to view a tree of the current folder and all descending files & folders.

In File Explorer under Windows 8.1:

- Select folder
- Press Shift, right-click mouse, and select "Open command window here"
- Type `tree /f > tree.txt` and press Enter
- Use MS Word to open "tree.txt"
- The dialog box "File Conversion - tree.txt" will open
- For "Text encoding" tick the "MS-DOS" option

You now have an editable tree structure file.

This works for versions of Windows from Windows XP to Windows 8.1.

Comment: That's something, but I need it in the GUI.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Windows 7 command prompt.

Comment: That's great. Is there a way to tell it ignore hidden folders and set the number of leafs to show? Thank You.

Comment: There is an ascii variant, which may be preferable for opening the file in Notepad or anything other Word. Replace the command at step three with "tree /f /a > tree.txt" and ignore steps four to six.

Comment: Works great on Windows 10's `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Type tree /f > tree.doc and press Enter to save to Word format.

Comment: And if the user does not have Admin rights?

Answer (score 80):

> tree /f /a

**About**

The Windows command `tree /f /a` produces a tree of the current folder and all files & folders contained within it in ASCII format.

The output can be redirected to a text file using the `>` parameter.

**Method**

For Windows 8.1 or Windows 10, follow these steps:

1. Navigate into the folder in file explorer.
2. Press Shift, right-click mouse, and select "Open command window here".
3. Type `tree /f /a > tree.txt` and press Enter.
4. Open the new `tree.txt` file in your favourite text editor/viewer.

*Note: Windows 7, Vista, XP and earlier users can type `cmd` in the run command box in the start menu for a command window.*

Answer (score 27):

I recommend **WinDirStat**.

I frequently use WinDirStat to create screen shots for user documentation of open folders and their contents.

It even uses the correct icons for Windows registered file types.

All I would say is missing is an option to display the files without their icons. I can live without it personally, since I am usually pasting the image into a paint program or Visio to edit it, but it would still be a useful feature.

Comment: WinDirStat is a brilliant program and the pillow charts it proceduces are perfect for viewing huge files over an entire partition.

Comment: Am I missing something obvious, or do I have to click on the "+" for each directory to get it to expand the directory listing? I can't find any "expand all" option.

Comment: Does WinDirStat work well on Windows 10?    Last release seems 11 years old.

Comment: WinDirStat runs well on Windows 10

Comment: @RenniePet You are not missing anything obvious ... you do have to click on the "+" for each directory with WinDirStat. It's astounding that there still doesn't seem to be any utility for Windows that will fully expand a directory in a graphical view with a single click.

Comment: WinDirStat doesn't allow to select multiple folders and delete them which is what I need

Answer (score 14):

If it is just viewing in tree view,One workaround is to use the Explorer in Notepad++ or any other tools.

Comment: I couldn't find this, can you give some more details please?

Comment: View -> Folder as Workspace, then right click in Folder as Workspace pane, select Add, browse to the folder you want to view and click OK.

Answer (score 2):

TreeSize professional has what you want. but it focus on the sizes of folders and files.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Internet Explorer to browse folders and files together in tree. It is a file explorer in Favorites Window. You just need replace "favorites folder" to folder which you want see as a root folder

Comment: Does not work in Windows 10, it directly pops up the Windows Explorer _window_ with the selected path.