# Tensorflow: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, filepath

[Screenshot Provided here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fG5r.png)i have an issue with my code. I am trying to execute a machine learning model from teachable machines, with the code snippet that is provided. However, i keep getting the error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:"

```
import tensorflow.keras
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy as np

# Disable scientific notation for clarity
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

# Load the model
model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model(r'C:\Users\royst\Desktop\TF Files\keras_model.h5')

# Create the array of the right shape to feed into the keras model
# The 'length' or number of images you can put into the array is
# determined by the first position in the shape tuple, in this case 1.
data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)

# Replace this with the path to your image
image = Image.open(r'C:\Users\royst\Desktop\TF Files\test_photo.jpg')

#resize the image to a 224x224 with the same strategy as in TM2:
#resizing the image to be at least 224x224 and then cropping from the center
size = (224, 224)
image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

#turn the image into a numpy array
image_array = np.asarray(image)
    
# display the resized image
image.show()

# Normalize the image
normalized_image_array = (image_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.0) - 1

# Load the image into the array
data[0] = normalized_image_array

# run the inference
prediction = model.predict(data)
print(prediction)
```

and i am getting this output from the terminal window

```
runfile('C:/Users/royst/Desktop/TF Files/Code.py', wdir='C:/Users/royst/Desktop/TF Files')
WARNING:tensorflow:No training configuration found in the save file, so the model was *not* compiled. Compile it manually.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\royst\Desktop\TF Files\Code.py", line 17, in <module>
    image = Image.open(r'C:\Users\royst\Desktop\TF Files\test_photo.jpg')

  File "C:\Users\royst\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2878, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\royst\\Desktop\\TF Files\\test_photo.jpg'
```

the file is clearly there, and i have placed the test image in the same folder as the .py file. Please help.

Comment: probably you could attach tree too

Comment: Sorry, how do i do that?

Comment: get to the main directory where your package is in the terminal / command prompt and then type tree

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518646/tree-view-of-a-directory-folder-in-windows