# How to display project structure in java

Tags: java, directory, structure

I have a error in a project I am currently working on. I wanted to post the problem in Stack overflow and want to display project structure like this :

```
src
├── main
│   └── java
│       └── Main.java
├── manifest.txt
├── run.sh
└── test
    └── java
        └── MainTest.java
```

I have copied this structure from another question. I am currently using eclipse and maven as well. If i amnot clear about my question.. here it is again. how to get project structure of a java project I am working on-like done above- ?? )Sorry for the bad english. not my first language)

Comment: So, you're looking for a way to convert a file structure of a project to a plain-text visualization that makes it easy to post it on forums ? -  I think you should focus your question on that.  And then at the end of your question, just mention that it's a java project. (which is more of a detail).

Comment: You can use `tree` in command line. `tree [PATH]` https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree

Comment: @ocos and that works on linux and windows.

Comment: Nearly all well-known OS have `tree` program. I can confirm for linux, macos and windows. Just type it.

Comment: it was such a easy fix.. thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I know to resolve this is using OS commands. In that case, the question was already answwered in other posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518646/tree-view-of-a-directory-folder-in-windows)

In Windows you can run the following commands in a cmd terminal:

- `cd the\root\folder\of\your\project`
- `tree /f` or `tree /f > tree.txt`

In Linux, the *tree* command should be available in most distributions.
You could use it by typing in a command terminal:

- `tree /the/root/folder/of/your/project`

If you are looking for a specific feature in Eclipse, then I can't help you. I don't know if such a feature exists.