# Python not recognizing modules

Tags: python, module

I have a directory of scripts and folders. I have made separate scripts for organization purposes. The directory consists of PARENTFOLDER\modules\inherited\classes.py I have an **init**.py file in both modules and inherited because of dependencies in other scripts. I have another script called sequences.py in modules that has `from inherited import classes`. It's imported separately from a script called main.py in PARENTFOLDER. The problem is, when I run the script from main.py, it throws the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'inherited'`. It doesn't highlight 'inherited' in the syntax either. I don't know why it isn't recognising inherited as a module.

Currently, this is what the directory looks like:

```
.
├── assets
├── modules
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── inherited
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── classes.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── sequences.py
└── main.py
```

Comment: Could you provide a structure tree of your directory? Currently it's hard to tell which is in which.

Comment: @InSync I have added a screenshot of the directory. Tell me if this helps.

Comment: Inherited doesn't exist. modules.inherited does

Comment: The script that is importing classes.py is inside modules. So `modules.inherited` doesn't exist to the script. I have tried and it just says 'modules does not exist'.

Comment: Thanks. I converted it to text, since [we prefer text to images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See also questions on how to print a directory tree: [Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3455625), [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9518646).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import syntax seems to be incorrect, try using:

```
import modules.inherited.classes
```

or

```
from modules.inherited import classes
```

Comment: It still says 'No module named inherited'. It appears to not be recognizing inherited as a class.

Comment: I have edited my code to be `import modules.inherited.classes as classes` but it still says that modules doesn't exist, which makes sense because sequences.py is *inside* modules. It doesn't recognize inherited as a module either.

Comment: It is an absolute import, it starts from the root of the project.
which command do you use to run the script ?

Comment: The script is ran using main.py with `from modules import sequences`. The problem is coming from sequences.py in the line that attempts to import the classes.py module.

Comment: Yes but what is the command you run in your terminal ?

Comment: I don't run a command in the terminal. I run it from VSCode. The second option appears to be the correct answer. I have accepted your answer but I don't think it's registered yet. Thanks for your help!